# How to show that the following sequences exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For all $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists a sequence of rational numbers $(q_n)$ and a sequence of irrational numbers $(p_n)$ such that $$x = \mathrm {lim}(q_n) =  \mathrm {lim}(p_n)$$

I have seen this being used in some proofs that I am reading in my real analysis book. It seems that these sequences could be built using the density theorem but I do not see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider $a_n = \lfloor 2^nx\rfloor$ and $p_n = a_n2^{-n}$.
   $$
   a_n \le 2^nx < a_n + 1 \implies
   p_n\le x < p_n + 2^{-n}
   $$hence $p_n\to x$.
2. Make the same construction with $x-\sqrt{2} $ instead of $x$.
   You  get that $p_n \to x-\sqrt{2}$ and, with $q_n = p_n + \sqrt{2}\notin \Bbb Q$,
   $$
   q_n \to x
   $$

Comment: How do you get from $p_n\le x < p_n + 2^{-n}$
to $p_n\to x$?

Comment: $0\le x-p_n < 1/2^n$... take $N = -\log\epsilon / \log 2$ then $n>N \implies |x-p_n|  < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, which assumes a single fact: any interval $(a,b)\subset\mathbb R$ with $a<b$ contains at least one rational point and at least one irrational point (this is a weak assertion; of course there are infinitely many such points in any nonempty interval).

Choose $x\in\mathbb R$. To construct a sequence of rational numbers converging to $x$, first consider the intervals $I_n = (x-2^{-n},x+2^{-n})$. This is a family of smaller and smaller intervals centered at $x$. Now choose one rational point $q_n$ in each interval $I_n$, using our fact. It is easy to see that $q_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$ since the distance between $q_n$ and $x$ is less than $2^{-n}$, by construction.

To make an irrational sequence you can use almost exactly the same construction: replace every occurrence of the word "rational" with the word "irrational" in the last paragraph. 
This construction is not entirely satisfactory because it is *nonconstructive*, but I think it uses the density argument well enough.